# Error on building C++ code in node-gyp when using PathFileExists and PathQuoteSpaces from Shlwapi

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I'm really a noob in C++, but I have C++ code and when I run `node-gyp build` it throws:
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PathQuoteSpacesA`
and
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PathFileExistsA`.

My code:

```
#include <node.h>

#include <Shlwapi.h>

// Full path and name of the API
static char g_szAPI[MAX_PATH] = "";

// Handle on the QuickVision window used to comunicate
static HWND g_hWndQV = NULL;

BOOL StartQV(LPSTR lpszCmdLine)
{
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    char szCmd[1024];
    DWORD retval = 0;

    // First we get the installation path and name from the registry
    if (!GetApiFullNameFromRegistry(g_szAPI, sizeof(g_szAPI))) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // If the path name has spaces, the full path name must be enclosed with quotation marks before calling CreateProcess
    PathQuoteSpaces(g_szAPI); //<----throw error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PathQuoteSpacesA 

    return (BOOL)retval;
}

BOOL GetApiFullNameFromRegistry(char* szAPI, DWORD dwBufLen)
{
    HKEY hKey=0;
    LONG retval= -1;
    BOOL Flag = FALSE;

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REGISTRY_KEY, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey))
    {
        retval = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "MjExec", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)szAPI, &dwBufLen);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    Flag = ERROR_SUCCESS == retval && dwBufLen != 0;

    if (Flag) {
        Flag = PathFileExists(szAPI); //<----throw error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_PathFileExistsA 
    }

    return Flag;
}
```

When I comment the code that throws an error, the code is built successfully.

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: I run node-gyp build

Answer (score 2):

It was necessary to add `#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")` at the top of the script to solve the problem

Result:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib") // <-- adding this

#include <node.h>

#include <Shlwapi.h>

// Full path and name of the API
static char g_szAPI[MAX_PATH] = "";

// Handle on the QuickVision window used to comunicate
static HWND g_hWndQV = NULL;

BOOL StartQV(LPSTR lpszCmdLine)
{
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    char szCmd[1024];
    DWORD retval = 0;

    // First we get the installation path and name from the registry
    if (!GetApiFullNameFromRegistry(g_szAPI, sizeof(g_szAPI))) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // If the path name has spaces, the full path name must be enclosed with quotation marks before calling CreateProcess
    PathQuoteSpaces(g_szAPI); // <-- now it works fine

    return (BOOL)retval;
}

BOOL GetApiFullNameFromRegistry(char* szAPI, DWORD dwBufLen)
{
    HKEY hKey=0;
    LONG retval= -1;
    BOOL Flag = FALSE;

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REGISTRY_KEY, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &hKey))
    {
        retval = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "MjExec", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)szAPI, &dwBufLen);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    Flag = ERROR_SUCCESS == retval && dwBufLen != 0;

    if (Flag) {
        Flag = PathFileExists(szAPI); // <-- now it works fine
    }

    return Flag;
}
```